# Non uniform continuity of a function and almost periodicity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, number-theory, harmonic-analysis, periodic-functions

We say that a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ is almost periodic in the sense of Bohr if:

For every sequence $(t'_n)_{n\geq0}$, there's a sub-sequence $(t_n)_{n\geq0}$ such that $f(t+t_n)$ converges uniformly in $\mathbb{R}$ to a function $g(t)$ i.e.
$$\sup_{t\in \mathbb{R}}|f(t+t_n)-g(t)|\to 0, \ \ when \ \ n\to +\infty.$$

This class of functions was [proved](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/math/Besicovitch%20A.S.%20Almost%20Periodic%20Functions%20%28Dover,%201954%29%28192s%29.pdf) to be the closure under the uniform norm in $\mathbb{R}$ of the class of Trigonometric Polynomial with independent frequencies
$$P(t)=\sum_{k=0}^N a_ke^{ib_kt}$$

Almost periodic functions are uniformly continuous and this class contains the class of periodic functions, but functions like $f(t)=\sin(t)+\sin(t\sqrt2)$ are almost periodic but not periodic. We can show this by assuming it is periodic then get the contradiction $\sqrt2 \in \mathbb{Q}$.

A more general class is the class the almost automorphic functions. A continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ is almost automorphic if

For every sequence $(t'_n)_{n\geq0}$, there's a sub-sequence $(t_n)_{n\geq0}$ and a function $g$ such that for each $t\in \mathbb{R}$
$$|f(t+t_n)-g(t)|\to 0, \ \ when \ \ n\to +\infty.$$
and
$$|g(t-t_n)-f(t)|\to 0, \ \ when \ \ n\to +\infty.$$

This class is [proved](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC221119/) to contain the class of almost periodic functions.
A classic example of almost automoprhic function which is not almost periodic is:
$$f(t)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{2+\sin(t)+\sin(t\sqrt2)}\right)$$
To prove this, we only have to show that this function is not uniformly continuous(since almost periodic functions are uniformly continuous). But It seems like I cannot prove it. I also cannot prove that this function is almost automorphic using the definition.

Comment: I think it would be useful if we find a sequence $t_n$ such that $2+\sin(t_n)+\sin(t_n \sqrt 2)$ goes to $0$, or in other words $\sin(t_n)$ and $\sin(t_n\sqrt 2)$ going to $-1$ at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must see (read) the following work (of Bolis Basit and Hans Günzler, posted at  arxiv):

http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.2169

There you can find nice steps to prove the desired claims.

Best.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for !!!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I'd suggest looking carefully at a graph of this function, really quite remarkable. I'd look at the area with "sin(1/x)"  type behavior . The scale factor is 100 along the y-axis.  (This is intended to be a comment, but it's necessary to look at some areas that are clearly not well behaved. )

Comment: There's actually no $\sin(1/x)$ like area in the graph, those areas contains finite oscillations unlike $\sin(1/x)$. But the number of oscillations is not bounded as you move from "bad" area to "bad" area. I also saw that $2+\sin(t)+\sin(\sqrt 2 t)$ can never reach $0$ but there must be a sequence such that $2+\sin(t_n)+\sin(\sqrt 2 t_n)$ goes to $0$.  It seems to me like this has to do with how we can approximate $\sqrt 2$ with rationals.

Comment: Yes , I see, very interesting example.

Comment: It is a weird function :).